# How to have a small capital investment in US if I am out of the country?

Tags: united-states, investing, small-business

I would like to invest some money in US, but I don't know how I can grow my money or what business can be a good choice for my small capital (hundred of dollars). I am located at Mexico.

Comment: How small is the capital: Tens of dollars, thousands of dollars, millions of dollars? Scale could be a factor here to some extent.

Comment: hundred of dollars

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm located at Mexico

Comment: You can probably invest in a US stock ETF through a local broker. Research to see if you can fins a broker with a low minimum investment.

Comment: Ok, can you give me some reference or idea of what an ETF is?

Comment: ETFs (Exchange Traded Funds) are mutual funds which are bougt and sold through the stock market rather than by dealing directly with the investment house that runs them. I've never understood why this is considered an advantage, unlesx it's that they have a lower minimum entry point. In general, when anyone writes ETF, you can mentally add "or mutual fund". [Do we have a Canonical Answer for this?]

Answer (score 1):

For $100 you better just hold it in Mexico.  The cost of opening an account could eat 10% or more of your capital easily, and that won't be able to buy enough shares of an ETF or similar investment to make it worthwhile.

Comment: Some recommendation of how to invest in Mexico?